# White Space on top of website can't find the source?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a signup form for project odin currently and after reviewing my code there is an inexplicable white gap that is about 100px tall and I cannot find the source of the issue. This is causing problems for me as it is causing the rest of the website to appear longer then it should be. Please help me review my code to pinpoint the error causing the white gap on top of the screen. Thank you

```css
* {
  font-family: "Alata", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.leftScreen {
  background-image: url("bg.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 34%;
}

.logoBox {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  width: 100%;
  height: 15vh;
  margin-top: 165px;
}

.logo {
  background-image: url("logo.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 30vh;
  width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.formScreen {
  width: 66%;
  background-color: #f9fafb;
}

.upper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: left;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 35vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.upperText {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  width: 75%;
}

.lowerText {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.form {
  font-size: 1 rem;
  height: 30vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  gap: 80px;
  /* this will make children elements to be placed in one row*/
}

input {
  width: 200px;
}

label {
  display: block;
}

.form h2 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.finish {
  display: flex;
  align-items: left;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 35vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.accountBtn {
  background-color: rgb(89, 108, 72);
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 45px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.finish h3 {
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}

.login {
  color: green;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Login Form</title>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alata&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="leftScreen">
      <div class="logoBox">
        <div class="logo"></div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="upper">
      <div class="upperText">
        This is not a real online service! You know you need something like this in your life to help you realize your deepest dreams.
        <br />Sign up <em>now</em> to get started.<br />
      </div>
      <br />
      <div class="lowerText">You <em>know</em> you want to.</div>
    </div>

    <div class="form">
      <h2>Let's do this!</h2>
      <form action="#" method="get">
        <div class="row">
          <div>
            <label for="firstName"> First Name </label>
            <input type="firstName" id="firstName" name="firstName" />
          </div>

          <div>
            <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
            <input type="lastName" id="lastName" name="lastName" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="email">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" />
          </div>

          <div class="phoneNumber">
            <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
            <input type="tel" id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="password">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
          </div>

          <div class="pc">
            <label for="confirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>


    <div class="finish">
      <button class="accountBtn">Create Account</button>
      <h3>
        Already have an account?<a class="login" href="/login"> Log In</a>
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you applied `height: 100vh;` to the `.leftScreen` class, try `height: auto` or something else that suits your need.

Comment: hey sunny the problem does seem to be the .leftscreen section but changing height to auto doesn't make the image the full length of the screen is there another fix for this?

Comment: You can set the height of ```.logoBox``` and ```.logo``` class to ```100vh``` and remove ```margin-top: 165px``` from ```.logoBox``` class, and check the result.